# Diophantine equation of power 2

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to solve the following equation: $x^2-17y^2=104$ where $x,y$ are integers. I don't know how to proceed here. I have tried with mod $13$ and mod $17$ but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), which is _almost_ what you're looking for.

Comment: you can simply set $y=x+m$, then transform this equation into a quadratic equation depending on the value of the parameter $m$. You need to find the values of $m$ that make the discriminant of the quadratic a square by trial and error.

Comment: $y=\pm1$ and $x=\pm11$ are solutions.  Are you asking for more solutions?  infinitely many solutions?  all solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This really does show all solutions with the variables positive.

In the output below, we have a recursion, three term, but referring to every fourth line. We could write
$$ w_{n+8} = 66 w_{n+4} - w_n,  $$
for example
$$ 32923 = 66 \cdot 499 - 11 \; . \;   $$
In the same way
$$ v_{n+8} = 66 v_{n+4} - v_n,  $$
for example
$$ 7985 = 66 \cdot 121 - 1 \; . \;   $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    33   136
    8   33
  Automorphism backwards:  
    33   -136
    -8   33

  33^2 - 17 8^2 = 1

 w^2 - 17 v^2 = 104 =  2^3 13

Mon Apr 29 18:19:58 PDT 2019

w:  11  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  23  v:  5  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  79  v:  19  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  23 ,  -5
w:  227  v:  55  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  11 ,  -1
w:  499  v:  121
w:  1439  v:  349
w:  5191  v:  1259
w:  14971  v:  3631
w:  32923  v:  7985
w:  94951  v:  23029
w:  342527  v:  83075
w:  987859  v:  239591
w:  2172419  v:  526889
w:  6265327  v:  1519565
w:  22601591  v:  5481691
w:  65183723  v:  15809375
w:  143346731  v:  34766689

Mon Apr 29 18:22:04 PDT 2019

 w^2 - 17 v^2 = 104 =  2^3 13
```

Comment: Did you mean $ v_{n+8} = 66 v_{n+4} - \color{red}v_n,  $ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, got it.

Comment: @WillJagy, can you please provide details on how you derived those recursion relations (or links)?

Comment: @user25406:  note that $(33-8\sqrt{17})^n(33+8\sqrt{17})^n=1$ so if $(x-y\sqrt{17})(x+y\sqrt{17})=104$ then $[(x-y\sqrt{17})(33-8\sqrt{17})^n][(x+y\sqrt{17})(33+8\sqrt{17})^n]=104$

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$x^2-17y^2=104$

Above has parametric solution:

$x=[(11k^2-34k+187)/(k^2-17)]$

$y=[(k^2-22k-17)/(k^2-17)]$

For, $k=0$ we get:

$(x,y)=(11,1)$

Comment: How to find the parametric solution?

Comment: @spyer As Arthur commented to your question, this is related to Pell's equation. In fact, it is a "generalized Pell's equation", with details at [Solving the generalized Pell equation](https://thilinaatsympy.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/solving-the-generalized-pell-equation/), as well as other sites you can find with an online search.

Comment: For $k=0$ I get $(x,y)=(\color{red}-11,1), $ which is also a solution; what other values of $k$ give integer solutions $(x,y)$?

Comment: @spyer. Since, (x,y)=(11,1) is solution to the equation, you can parameterize it at (x=11+kt) & (y=1+t) & solve for (t) in term's of (k) & then substitute for (t) in (x=11+kt) & (y=1+t).

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- Modulo $17$ one has $x^2=2$ whose solutions in $\mathbb F_{17}$ are $x=6$ and $x=11$ so we have in $\mathbb Z$

$$x=17n+6\text{ and } x=17n+11$$ It follows respectively $$y^2=17n^2+12n-4\text{ and } y^2=17n^2+22n+1$$ Then we have the identities
$$(17n+6)^2-17(17n^2+12n-4)=104$$
$$(17m+11)^2-17(17m^2+22m+1)=104$$ It remains to study when $17n^2+12n-4$ and $17m^2+22m+1$ can be squares.

Some solutions of the first, $17n^2+12n-4=y^2$ are $n=-5,-1,1,13$ which give respectively $y=19,1,5,55$ so $ x=\sqrt{17y^2+104}=79,11,23,227$. Thus one has, as examples, the four solutions $$(x,y)=(79,19),(11,1),(23,5),(227,55)$$ but there must be many more, infinitely many probably.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $y=1$ and $x=11$ is a solution of $x^2-17y^2=104$.

As pointed out by others, so are $(x,y)=(23,5), (79,19),$ and $(227,55)$.

Once you have a solution $(x,y)$ to $x^2-17y^2=104$, another is $(33x+136y, 8x+33y)$.

That's because $33-17\times8^2=(33-8\sqrt{17})(33+8\sqrt{17})=1$,

so if $x^2-17y^2=(x-y\sqrt{17})(x+y\sqrt{17})=104$

then $(33-8\sqrt{17})(x-y\sqrt{17})(33+8\sqrt{17})(x+y\sqrt{17})=104=$

$[(33x+8\times17y)-(8x+33y)\sqrt{17})][(33x+8\times17y)+(8x+33y)\sqrt{17}].$

The above information gives all of the solutions listed by [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy).

Comment: $(x,y)=(33,8)$ is the smallest solution to the [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)$x^2-17y^2=1$